# Use full page multiple times in different tabs

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, fullpage.js

[image]

As you can see I have different tabs. I want to use the full-page method for each group( Each group has its own section slide ) separately. As I can use the full page only once I'm stuck. Can you tell me how to do this?

It's working fine for the first group but not working on the second. I also tried the destroy method mentioned in the documentation of fullpage.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can destory and initialisee fullpage.js every time you need a new instance.

Use the `fullpage_api.destory('all')` method and then initialise it again.

It should look kind of like this:

```js
function showTab1(){
    fullpage_api.destroy('all');

    // loading HTML for tab1
    loadHTML();

    new fullpage('#fullpage', options);
}

function showTab2(){
    fullpage_api.destroy('all');

    // loading HTML for tab2
    loadHTML();

    new fullpage('#fullpage', options);
}
```

Comment: Hi Alvaro, First of all, thank you so much for answering. It's working but not properly. As by default tab 1 has id="fullpage" when I go to tab 2 it is removing id from tab1 and adding id to tab 2 and tab 2 also working fine.
But when I came back to tab 1 its not working although it is adding id in tab-1 and removing from tab2 I inspect the dom there is 'fb-destroyed' class in it(tab 1)
Can you tell me how to solve this issue?
Thanks

Comment: The id should be unique. Better not to change ids. Just use a different one per tab or the same for all, but the same id should only be present one time in the dom.

Comment: Hi Alvaro, I did it Thank you very much

Comment: Please accept the answer hitting the green tick, this way serve as a way for others to come to this issue to know that your issue was fixed with this solution.

Comment: Understood. I did